# Sphinx does not change version number

Tags: python, versioning, python-sphinx

I changed the version number of my project in conf.py:

```
version = '0.0.2'
```

But when I generate a new html (make html), the version is always: 0.0.1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to add to the discussion. You could simplify your workflow and if your version usually is the same as the release, you could put it this way:

```
# The short X.Y version.
version = '0.0.1'
# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags.
release = version
```

Then you will only need to change the first value.

Answer (score 4):

You should have to update the release = '' in the conf.py. Version is the short x.y version internally. Release is the full version that is added during the sphinx build to the project.

In your conf.py just change.

```
# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags.
release = '0.0.2'
```

Then rerun make html.